# Sorting and moving a directory with files into subdirectories

Tags: bash, files, sort

Im using Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon, based on Ubuntu 18.04.
(I hope Im not 'cursing in church' by that info .. ! But its functionally the same as Ubuntu 18.04 to 95%).

Trying to move files in a folder into alphabetically named subdirs.
Only based on first letter. Generating subfolder names of one character length, one level deep, according to the first letter of names present on files or irrespective of subfolder letter being present as files.
(Empty subfolder not a problem).

Files starting with numbers or other than a character could go into a ' # ' named folder.
Or a folder starting with its number like the letters.

BASH code was requested !

Comment: 1) Do you mean you want to make subdirectories a..z then test a file and move it into the subdirectory which matches the first character of a file?  2) If so, how will you handle exceptions, where a file does not begin with a letter from a to z? 3) which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) & 4) which release number?  Different distros have different tools, you see. Please click [edit] & add that info to your question so all the facts are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment; that's our channel to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something simple, I would start with something like that :

```
cd <yourdir>
for f in *; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    mkdir -p "${f:0:1}"
    mv "$f" "${f:0:1}"
  fi
done
cd -
```

You go to you directory and for everything present in this directory :

- you test if its a plain file (not a directory or something else),
- make a subdirectory named after the first character of the filename (mkdir -p →  no error if it already exists)
- move the file in the subdirectory

Finaly you go back to the directory you where before (cd -)

Comment: Sorry to take so long to reply ! But this did the trick for a folder of .prg c64 emulator files !! Thanks a bunch !